# How to identify patterns in a tensor-polynomial and replace appropriate symbol?

Tags: function-construction

I want to write a function `tensorReplace[input]` that takes a tensor polynomial in $r_i$ such as $r_i r_j r_k+r_i q_j q_k +q_i q_j q_k$ , and replaces each monomial with a function `f[{idx}]` using the rule $r_i\rightarrow f(\{i\})$, $r_i r_j\rightarrow f(\{i,j\})$, *etc.* leaving the $q$'s and another other symbols untouched.

So for in the example above, if my input is
$$r_i r_j r_k+r_i q_j q_k +q_i q_j q_k\,,$$
I am shooting for an output

$$f(\{i,j,k\})+f(\{i\})q_i q_j+q_i q_j q_k\,.$$

I also need to allow the possibility where a vector with same index is squared (repeated in a monomial) given the obvious $r_i^2\rightarrow f(\{i,i\})$.

I don't know how to even begin, because my input could be an arbitrarily high order polynomial in $r$, with many terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're talking about polynomials, it's only natural to try and solve this using the built-in functions for extracting polynomial coefficients and variables. It leads to this:

```
replaceR[poly_, name_, replacementName_] := 
 Module[{vars = Cases[Variables[poly], name[_]]}, 
  Apply[Plus, 
   CoefficientRules[poly, vars] /. 
    Rule[expo_, coeff_] :> 
     coeff replacementName[
       Inner[Table[#[[1]], {#2}] &, vars, expo, Join]]]]

replaceR[4 q[i] r[h]^2 + 2 r[i] r[j] r[k], r, f]
```

> `2 f[{i,j,k}]+4 f[{h,h}] q[i]`

The first argument is the polynomial, the second the name to be replaced (`r` in your question), and the third argument is the name of the function you called `f`. First, I use `Variables` and select the ones that are of the form `r[_]`; then `CoefficientRules` gives us the powers of all the variables with their coefficients, in a simple list that can be rewritten one monomial at a time into a new form involving `f[{...}]`.

The special case of a constant in the polynomial leads to a corresponding empty function,

```
replaceR[1, r, f]
```

> `f[{}]`

I think that's consistent, but if you don't like it one can always append a replacement rule like `/. f[{}] :> 1`. The use of polynomial manipulation functions makes it possible in principle to input the polynomial in non-expanded form, too.

Comment: This is my favorite! I am especially impressed by your correct guess that a constant should yield `f[{}]`.  Your code and the accompanying explanation was clear enough for me to be able to tweak and embed it into my program.  One question/observation: this code seems to work correctly even when the input polynomial is not expanded out in full: for example $(r_i+q_i)(r_j+q_j)$ works as intended.  At what point does Mathematica know to expand everything out?

Comment: Thanks - in the docs for [`CoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoefficientRules.html) it says that the whole thing "works whether or not poly is explicitly given in expanded form." Of course the other answers would also work if you explicitly use `Expand` first, but in the polynomial manipulation functions that's built in...

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation:

```
start = r[i] r[j] r[k] + r[i] q[j] q[k] + q[i] q[j] q[k];

start /. r[x_]^y_ :> r @@ Table[x, {y}] //. r[a__] r[b_] :> r[a, b] /. r[x__] :> f[{x}]
```

> ```
> f[{i, j, k}] + f[{i}] q[j] q[k] + q[i] q[j] q[k]
> ```

Comment: Nice and short. The only way I could trip it up was by leaving a power in symbolic form, as in `r[i]^n`. That's probably not going to happen, though...

Comment: Yes, this is very short indeed!  And, yes, the power will always be a numeric integer; never symbolic.

Answer (score 1):

```
(r@i r@j r@k 2 + 4 q@i r@h r@h) /. x_ :> Sort /@ x /. PatternSequence[(r@x_) ..] :> f@{x} 
                   //.  f[{x_}] f[{y__}] :> f[{x, y}] //. f[{s__}]^n_ :> f[Array[s &, n]]

(*
2 f[{k, i, j}] + 4 f[{h, h}] q[i]
*)
```

**Edit**

as a function:

```
tensorRepl[i_, r_, f_] := i /. x_ :> Sort /@ x /. PatternSequence[(r@x_) ..] :> f@{x} //. 
                         f[{x_}] f[{y__}] :> f[{x, y}] //. f[{s__}]^n_ :> f[Array[s &, n]]

tensorRepl[(r@i r@j r@k 2 + 4 q@i r@h r@h), r, f]
(*
2 f[{k, i, j}] + 4 f[{h, h}] q[i]
*)
```

Comment: +1 But I just noticed it doesn't work if there's a constant term, as in `1 + r[i] ...`

Comment: @Jens Good point. The OP's example perhaps (mis)guided me into thinking of sums of products with the same number of tensorial terms. Anyway, adding it's solved with the addition of a last `/. Sort[x_]:>x`